# Command processor has stopped working

Tags: c++

I was writing a code for exception handling on Visual C++ 2010 .Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Localize a try/catch to a function.
void Xhandler(int test)
{
  try{
    if(test) throw test;
  }
  catch(int i) {
    cout << "Caught Exception #: " << i << '\n';
  }
}

int main()
{
  cout << "Start\n";

  Xhandler(1);
  Xhandler(2);
  Xhandler(0);
  Xhandler(3);

  cout << "End";

  return 0;
}
```

The Program executed properly and the output was the as expected.But when I pressed the close button for closing the console then an error came that `cmd has stopped working`
[image: Here is the image]

.Then I ran my previous code that executed properly ,they  also gave the   same error
.
Can anybody tell why it is happening?Is it a problem with the Visual c++ 2010 or the code

Comment: Your `cmd.exe` is infected by a virus :P

Comment: @POW are you serious?

Comment: With _"I ran my previous code that executed properly ,they also gave the same error"_ , I can think of only a corrupted executable. Idk, wait for some answers

Comment: I ran Debugger ,the results were that Native has exited with code 0 .I think It means the program has  ended properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is not with your code. The problem is within your compiler tool chain. You probably are using Qt, and the tool chain has a problem causing this. Google the message you get when you crash with your IDE.

Here's a simple experiment to prove what I'm saying: just run this code:

```
int main()
{
  cout << "Start\n";


  cout << "End";

  return 0;
}
```

And your program will crash, which means you have no problems with exceptions or anything else in your code, but with your tool chain.

Comment: Although the program is displaying correct result and successfully ends when a press any key ,but when I specifically press close button then this error comes

Comment: I know that, and that's why I'm telling you that your code is not the problem. The problem is with your compiler's tool chain. Make sure your compiler is configured properly. This is a compiler problem, not a code problem.

Comment: Ok I got your point but how come the problem came suddenly .I didn't changed any compiler setting

Comment: That's a very big question that I can't answer directly. I would say that you close this question and start a new one with a new topic to draw the specialists attention.

Comment: should I flag this question for moderator attention

Comment: @SamerAfach, OK wow. You just **knew the answer**! This is what SO is all about!

Comment: @Ben That's experience ;-) . I had some painful experience with that some time ago.